# Attempting to override dictionary ToString for ComboBox

Tags: c#, dictionary, overriding, tostring

I am attempting to store metadata in my ComboBox elements by overriding a Dictionary<>'s ToString(). However, my ToString() override does not appear to be executing, and I can't figure out why. The ComboBox displays "(Collection)" instead of the value I specify. Is there a step I'm missing to get the ComboBox to use my ToString() override?

```
public class ComboElement : Dictionary<string,object> {
  protected string defaultkey = "";
  public ComboElement( SqlDataReader sdr, string defkey )
    : base() {
    defaultkey = defkey;
    for ( int field = 0; field < sdr.FieldCount; field++ ) {
      this.Add( sdr.GetName( field ), sdr[field] );
    }
  }
  public override string ToString() {
    return "GLURP"; //
    //if ( this.ContainsKey( this.defaultkey ) == true ) { return this[this.defaultkey].ToString(); } else return "";
  }
}
```

Code to populate ComboBox on DropDown:

```
      while ( sdr.Read() == true ) {
        ComboElement ce = new ComboElement( sdr, "filename" );
        string tstring = ce.ToString(); // Correct value
        cmbFiles.Items.Add( ce ); // Displays "(Collection)"
      }
```

Comment: WinForms, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try adding a `DisplayValue` property to your `ComboElement` class and then setting the `DisplayMember` of the `ComboBox` to the name of this property.

Comment: I have added the property public string DisplayValue { get { if ( this.ContainsKey( this.defaultkey ) == true ) { return this[this.defaultkey].ToString(); } else return ""; } } and set the DisplayMember to DisplayValue, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Windows Forms code special-cases some .NET classes and doesn't call `ToString()` on them to get a textual representation as advertised.

You can work around this by making `ComboElement` implement `IDictionary<string, object>` instead of deriving from `Dictionary<string, object>`, and write implementations of all methods that forward to a `Dictionary` member that `ComboElement` would aggregate. That's a lot of trouble to go¹ to for no real gain, but it's the only way you are going to get the behavior you want.

¹Or possibly not much trouble at all: JetBrains ReSharper (which I use all the time and recommend highly) can write all the forwarding code automatically for you.